# How can I measure my tendon length?

Tags: tendons, medical-imaging, measurement

I read on [Wikipedia's page on tendon](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tendon&oldid=775545083) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170505234817/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tendon)):

> Tendon length varies in all major groups and from person to person.

How can I measure my tendon length?

I am mostly interested in the tendons that attach to the epicondyles of the humerus.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://redd.it/69i83w
- http://qr.ae/TbAyEF